# fastest way to make a readonly copy of an array of structure?

Tags: .net

I'm currently using something like

```
c#
var myvar = directcast(myarrayofstruct.clone(), mystruc());

vb.net
dim myvar = directcast(myarrayofstruct.clone, mystruc())
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `Clone()` is about as fast as you'll get, yes.